# Move images from www to documents for update

Tags: cordova

My application have images (.jpg) in www/files/ for a products gallery.

When the application run i check for uddated images in a webserver if have updates for files, i'll need to save these new images.

I have seen that it cannot write in www folder, phonegap saved new images in document folder(fileSystem.root.fullPath).

But how i can transfer the initial images from www/files to documents folder?

or

Have a method to save directly to documents folder in the install or in the first run?

Have a good practice for this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you read phonegap [document](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0rc2/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry) about file and directory, you'll get detail about copyTo method which used to copy file and directory.

**copyTo**

Copy a directory to a different location on the file system. It is an error to attempt to:

copy a directory inside itself at any depth;
copy a directory into its parent if a name different from its current one is not provided.
Directory copies are always recursive - that is, they copy all contents of the directory.

**Parameters**:

- parent - The parent directory to which to copy the directory.
  (DirectoryEntry)
- newName - The new name of the directory. Defaults to the current name
  if unspecified. (DOMString)
- successCallback - A callback that is called with the DirectoryEntry
  object of the new directory.(Function)
- errorCallback - A callback that is called if an error occurs when
  attempting to copy the underlying directory. Invoked with a FileError
  object. (Function)

**Quick Example**

```
function win(entry) {
    console.log("New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert(error.code);
}

function copyDir(entry) {
    var parent = document.getElementById('parent').value,
        parentName = parent.substring(parent.lastIndexOf('/')+1),
        newName = document.getElementById('newName').value,
        parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry(parentName, parent);

    // copy the directory to a new directory and rename it
    entry.copyTo(parentEntry, newName, success, fail);
}
```

In OnDeviceReady method check whether files folder is present or not in document directory, If not present, execute above code to copy `www/files` folder into the document directory.

Comment: Thank you, but your answer not help me.
I have seen that cannot access www files with filesystem and the people use ajax to read the files for save in local documents (IOS).
I wanna see a sample or know the best practices for this.